# how to make enemy change direction PYTHON

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I'm trying to program a small game with pygame where the objective is to catch as much poop as possible and avoid the infected poop, but I can't get the enemy to switch directions when it hits a wall.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('POOPISTINKI')

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
game_running = True
pl_x = int(screen_width/10)
pl_y = int(screen_height/2)
pl_width = 80
pl_height = 40
pl_vel = 30
en_width = 80
en_height = 40
en_x = screen_width - screen_width/10 - en_width
en_y = int(screen_height/2)
en_yvel = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

while game_running:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4 and pl_y > pl_vel:
                pl_y -= pl_vel

            elif event.button == 5 and pl_y < screen_height - pl_width:
                pl_y += pl_vel

    if en_y == 0:
        en_y += en_yvel

    if en_y == screen_height - en_height:
        en_y -= en_yvel

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (105, 255, 125), (pl_x, pl_y, pl_width, pl_height))
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 125, 115), (en_x, en_y, en_width, en_height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You only need a single call to `pygame.display.update()` too.  It will "flush" all the changes to the window.

Comment: ohh sorry i programmed a bit on my laptop when i was on vacation and the internet was slow af so i must accidentally have clicked the wrong button but the answer was great worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert `en_yvel` once the enemy `en_y` hits the top or bottom of the window.
Furthermore I recommend to use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) respectively [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the flops per seconds.

```py
en_yvel = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while game_running:
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

    en_y += en_yvel
    if en_y <= 0 or en_y >= screen_height - en_height:
        en_yvel = -en_yvel

    # [...]
```